# Can't compile Environment.Exit in .NET Core

Tags: c#, dnx, .net-core

Related: [System.Environment in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497438/system-environment-in-net-core)

I'm trying to compile a program which uses `Environment.Exit` in .NET Core. I've used `yo aspnet` to create the default console application, installed `System.Runtime.Extensions` and then added a call to `Environment.Exit(1)` (full sample [on github](https://github.com/nyctef/environment-exit-test/tree/master/ConsoleApplication)). When running `dnu build` I get this error:

`C:\git\environmentexit\ConsoleApplication\Program.cs(13,25): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0117: 'Environment' does not contain a definition for 'Exit'`

As far as I can tell, [this corefx pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/4266) should mean that `Environment.Exit` is exposed, so I can't figure out what else I'm missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: That pull request is recent, very unlikely to be integrated into 5.0.  Short from keeping up with the rapid changes, you can use FailFast() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there a reference for what's available at the moment somewhere? I found http://dotnet.github.io/api/System.Environment.html (after a lot of searching) but that lists `Environment.Exit`. And yeah, I'm using `FailFast` for now, but it looks like a crash so it isn't ideal.

Comment: It is open source, the source is the reference.  I use Reflector to look at the reference assemblies, works pretty well.  This might be integrated into MSDN some day but it has to stabilize first.  Right now it is changing far too quickly to make that practical.

Comment: I can confirm that `Environment.Exit` really not exist in `1.0.0-rc1-update1`, but it do exist in the current latest build. If you want I can post the answer, where I describe step by step how to install and to compile your demo project using the latest night build (today it's `1.0.0-rc2-16343`) and how to go back to currently last stable `1.0.0-rc1-update1`.

Comment: @Oleg I think that's probably going to be the answer, yeah. I'm still curious why it isn't in rc1 (it seems to be in the source code according to the repo - see comments on Lex's answer) but it sounds like using the nightly will fix it for now, and that's probably useful information for other people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all I want to confirm that the problem exist in the current stable version of DNX: `1.0.0-rc1-update1` installed together with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. The problem is *already fixed* in the current unstable build `1.0.0-rc2-16343`.

I try to describe below very detailed how everybody can reproduce the problem step by step. In the next step I would show how to install the latest *unstable* build of DNX (it's `1.0.0-rc2-16343` today) and to compile your demo **successfully**. Finally I show how to uninstall *unstable* build of DNX go back to `1.0.0-rc1-update1`.

First of all it's important to understand that one can install **multiple** version of DNX. On the other side all the packages resolved by usage "Restore Packages" in the context menu of the project or by usage of "dnu restore" command will be saved (cached) in the **common folder** `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages`. The dependencies will be resolved from NuGet. To be exactly there are the file `%APPDAT%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` which contains the configuration of NuGet with URLs used for resolving of dependencies. Thus one can have wrong results after "playing" with different NuGet configurations  and with different versions of DNX. I find such behavior as the large design problem of DNX today. I hope that it will be fixed soon.

In any way I strictly recommend to **delete all files** from `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages` to have deterministic results. Additionally one should verify NuGet configuration to load the files only from the starndard NuGet source `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` (or `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/`) and *optionally* from `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json` (or `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2`), which can contains additional ASP.NET stable packages. One can either edit the file `%APPDAT%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` manually or to check the described above sources in Visual Studio in menu: "Tools" / "NuGet Package Manager" / "Package Manager Settings" and choosing "Package Sources" finally.

1) I removed all files under `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages`
2) verified using "dnvm list" that I have only `1.0.0-rc1-final` and `1.0.0-rc1-update1` versions of DNX. I uninstalled some unneeded version using something like "dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc2-16343 -r coreclr -arch x86" and verified that the `1.0.0-rc1-update1` is default by usage "dnvm upgrade". After that the "dnvm list" displayed:

[image]

3) set only `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` in my initial configuration:

[image]

After building of your demo with `Program.cs`

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye, cruel world");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

and `project.json`

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ConsoleApplication Console Application",
  "authors": [
    ""
  ],
  "tags": [
    ""
  ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "ConsoleApplication"
  },
  "commands": {
    "ConsoleApplication": "ConsoleApplication"
  },
  "dependencies": { },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-*",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-*",
        "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.11-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following dependencies resolved

[image]

and the error message

[image]

---

Now I installed the latest *unstable* DNX using

```
dnvm upgrade -u -r coreclr -arch x64
dnvm upgrade -u -r clr -arch x64
dnvm upgrade -u -r coreclr
dnvm upgrade -u -r clr
```

The command "dnvm list" displayed

[image]

After that I modified the NuGet configuration to use `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json` additionally:

[image]

Then I modified `sdk.verison` of `global.json` from `"1.0.0-rc1-update1"` to `"1.0.0-rc2-16343"` in the GUI of Visual Studio:

[image]

and saved the changes. After that I made "Restore Packages" and build the project once more. I get the following versions of dependencies:

[image]

and the program could be executed **without any error**.

It's vary important to mention that even if we would change the `sdk.verison` back to `"1.0.0-rc1-update1"` we will still have the same resolution of dependences from `rc2-16343` because it will be used the packages cashed in `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages`. It's really important to change NuGet configuration to original state (uncheck URL `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json`) and delete all `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages`. I would recommend you to deinstall unneded night build of DNX by usage of

```
dnvm upgrade
dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc2-16343 -r coreclr -arch x64
dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc2-16343 -r clr -arch x64
dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc2-16343 -r coreclr
dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc2-16343 -r clr
```

After all the steps one should have the same state in "dnvm list" as initially. One can verify that `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes` don't contains any directories with `1.0.0-rc2-16343`, the file `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\alias\default.txt` contains `dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1` and the PATH contains only `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin` and not references to `1.0.0-rc2-16343`. In other words we finished our test and are returned back to stable rc1-update1.

Comment: Wow, that's quite an answer! Thanks for all the detail :)