# how do i uninstall old versions of dnx?

Tags: dnx, dnvm

I want to remove all the beta versions of clr and coreclr
I cant see them in programs and features.

I am running Windows 7

I deleted all files in %USERPROFILE%.dnx\packages
but when I run

```
dnvm list
```

I still see them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `dnvm uninstall` command. For example

```
dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc2-16343 -r coreclr -arch x64
```

You should just change the `default` to another dnx if you want to uninstall the current one. I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34421286/315935) step by step how one can install a new version of dnx, try it and then uninstall it.

You will see that the most what do `dnvm uninstall` is deleting of the folder existing under `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes`.

Comment: Thanks, I could not see the point of keeping the old beta versions available, which is why i wanted to remove them from the list.

Comment: @kirsteng: You are welcome! I uninstalled old versions from my computer too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also delete the folders in c:/users//.dnx/runtimes

They were talking about this [dnvm uninstall on github](https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/issues/254).
Make sure you have an up-to-date dnvm with dnvm update-self.